# How to configure Visual Studio not to output warnings from libraries?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-warnings

Is there any way to prevent Visual Studio from printing out warnings from included libraries?

\Wall gives me loads of warnings from STL and Qt headers, although I only want to see those originating from my own code (i.e. the code which is part of the current Visual Studio project).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pragma to set the warning levels for each file.

So before you include

```
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable : 4705 )
#pragma warning( disable : 4706 )
#pragma warning( disable : 4707 )
// Some code

#include your files here

#pragma warning( pop )
```

More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That's the only portable way (if using -isystem with other compilers):

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: ...)
#endif
#include <Q...>
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma warning(pop)
#endif
```

Hopefully they will implement isystem one of these days:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/14717934-add-a-cl-exe-option-for-system-headers-like-gcc-s