# Cannot disable warnings caused by the Boost Library

Tags: c++, boost, suppress-warnings

I am trying to eliminate the warnings in my project so I can turn on the flag that treats warnings as errors. The project uses the boost library, specifically the Concept_check.hpp and cuthill_mckee_ordering.hpp files. The warnings 4510 and 4610 are shown in the concept_check.hpp file and I have tried to disable them using #pragma warning push and pop. The warnings are caused by the boost library trying to instantiate a class using the template found in concept_check.cpp when there is no constructor written for it.

My Question is this: Is there a more sure fire way that I can disable these warnings without modifying the boost code? I am using Visual studio 2010.

Comment: Instantiating a class using a constructor that doesn't exist is an error. That's not what that warning means.

Comment: Please show real code and the actual warnings you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking in the wrong direction. As Alan Stokes pointed out, the warning is there for a reason. I have three hints that are perhaps not the answers you expect, but may bring an *acceptable* solution:

1. Instead of **silencing the warning**, just **fix the error**. I don't know your code, but there are [other people](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/concept-check-silence-gcc-warnings-td2672144.html) that had a similar problem which was possible to fix by *just declaring* a variable.
2. Another question is: why do you want to turn all your warnings into errors? Is it really neccessary? I agree that normal code should always compile without warnings. But these warnings are not originating from your own code. Consider a [static code-checker](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) that warns you about issues where your compiler is blind about.
3. If you **have to** use `-WX`, move the offending code into a static object/library/module so you will be bothered about the warning only when you need to recompile this module. You could use specific compile options for this module, to get the warnings completely out of your way.

---

There is another possibility, but I'm not able to check whether it really works. According the [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thxezb7y(v=vs.100).aspx) it is possible to set the warning level of specific warnings. (there are similar [options for GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html)). First, switch all warnings to error:

```
/WX
```

Then, set the warning level of the two offending warnings to zero:

```
/W04510 /W04610
```

A complete commandline would look like this:

```
cl source.cpp /WX /W04510 /W04610
```

The best solution would be to combine this with hint 3 above. This way, the specific compiler options are only used for the files that cause the warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834304/how-to-configure-visual-studio-not-to-output-warnings-from-libraries) solutions work.

You can disable specific warning from a .h file (#pragma warning( disable: ... ).

Comment: Unfortunately, this strategy has not worked for me in this situation. It is usually my go to way of suppressing warnings but for some reason it won't work for me here.